# How to fit CSS to the screen size?

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS code, my problem is that because of the `padding-top` (to have some space from the top) my page is too big what makes it to have 'scroll' option and it doesn't fit the whole screen.

How do I make it so the scroll option will be disabled?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    color: #444;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

I tried to add `overflow: hidden;` which works but then it cuts off some of my divs at the bottom

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to show some HTML so we can see the problem. Also explain your goal more clearly. All you've told us is what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.container` to include the padding in the percentage value for `height`.

Answer (score 0):

Relys. You can using the

```
box-sizing: border-box
```

on your container div to include your padding.